# Best practices for runtime code generation in Ruby

Tags: ruby, compilation, code-generation, runtime-compilation

I recently started playing around with parsers and parser generators and their uses in DSL design. To get things started, and to kill two birds with one stone, I wrote a pure Ruby PEG parser DSL by stealing some ideas from peg.js. The difference is that peg.js will compile the grammar to JavaScript whereas my library uses the interpreter pattern combined with some syntax sugar that Ruby provides to do everything in pure Ruby. This adds some non-trivial overhead that I would like to avoid.

To reduce some of the overhead I started thinking about compiling some of the parsing expressions that are generated into lower level representation. One idea I had was to use `eval` to evaluate the string representation of the code within the singleton class of some object. Here's some pseudo-code to demonstrate the process:

```
# will be used to pass CompiledExpression instance to `eval`
def get_binding(instance)
  instance.instance_eval { binding }
end

# an instance of this class will be used with `eval` 
# to define an `execute` method
class CompiledExpression
  attr_reader :code_repr
  # need to instantiate with a string representation of 
  # the code we are going to use to define the `execute` method
  def initialize(code)
    @code_repr = code
  end
end

# create the instance and define `execute` for that instance
# by evaluating the code representation
compiled_expr = CompiledExpression.new

# first way
eval "class << self; def execute; " +
    "#{compiled_expr.code_repr}; end; end", get_binding(compiled_expr)

# second way
compiled_expr.instance_eval "class << self; " +
    "def execute; #{compiled_expr.code_repr}: end; end"

# third way
compiled_expr.singleton_class.class_eval "def execute; " + 
    "#{compiled_expr.code_repr}; end"

# fourth way
compiled_expr.instance_eval "def execute; " + 
    "#{compiled_expr.code_repr}; end"
```

I want to know whether there are other/better approaches to accomplishing such code generation? I'm new to this stuff so I'm probably missing something obvious.

Answer (score 2):

I'm still trying to understand what you are trying to accomplish, but there are already a few Ruby parser/parser generators that you might be interested in exploring.

**Treetop**: The parser I'm most familiar with, it's a peg parser that can be dynamically run or *compile a grammar into a pure Ruby parser*. [Treetop](http://treetop.rubyforge.org/).

**Parslet**: This is another peg parser that has a simpler design than Treetop and "better" error reporting. [Parslet](http://kschiess.github.com/parslet/).

**Citrus**: Another parser, one I'm not as familiar with; I don't think this is a *pure* peg parser though. [Citrus](https://github.com/mjijackson/citrus).

Comment: I know about all those libraries. I'm just reinventing the wheel to learn some things at a deeper level. I'm trying to figure out what the best way is to generate code at runtime in Ruby. I want to know if there are better/easier ways of generating code other than evaluating strings with the actual code.